# Anatomy of a cookie

Tags: php, security, cookies, yii

I am new to cookies . Trying to understand the structure of this cookie my website sets when a user logs in . I am building in PHP using Yii , I have also enabled cookie validation in config . Just want to make sure if it's working properly (with `HMAC` token being set) and if I am open to any vulnerabilities .

> dd3b7ffe10018a899b39986a9d94dfd3b64e7e4as:248:"05035a5ae619356a622ed6ed805b6695a4fd6c44a:4:{i:0;s:18:"mjkvj003@gmail.com";i:1;s:18:"mjkvj003@gmail.com";i:2;i:604800;i:3;a:4:{s:6:"userid";s:2:"10";s:8:"username";s:18:"mjkvj003@gmail.com";s:4:"type";s:10:"diagnostic";s:6:"status";s:7:"pending";}}";

The cookie name in itself is a random 32 character alphanumeric sequence . I also have a phpsession cookie storing session id separately . Here `mjkvj003@gmail.com` is the username , type and status are application related variables . 
I thought cookies used `=` for assigning values but here i see `:` being used . Is this correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the contents of a cookie. It's a serialized representation of the contents of PHP's [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php), which is produced by calling [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) on that array.

The cookie itself contains just the session id, which lets PHP know which serialized session data to `unserialize` and make available as `$_SESSION` to your script.

Comment: So 'i' must be the array index then ? What does 'a:4:' refer to ? It has been used twice before starting a curly bracket ?

Comment: `a:4` means that an array with 4 elements follows. `i:0:s:18:"..."` means that the first element of the array has an integer key of `0` and its value is a string of length 18 with the following contents, etc. All of this is just how `serialize` works. Use `var_dump` and `serialize` to see how values map to serialized representations.

Comment: That explains a lot !! But I still do not understand the very first line , My php session Id is nowhere close to the strings given in the first line . And also this particular part in the middle line : ' i:2;i:604800;i:3;a:4: '

Comment: @VarunJain: The first line does not make sense as written, so there's copy paste trouble somewhere. For the rest please refer to http://unserialize.net/.

Comment: I think the first line might just be the HMAC token set by yii. Thanks for your time and help !!

Answer (score 0):

The first line is the HMAC token set by Yii . Dug through the framework files and found that they set the token and also serialize the cookie data .